# Applying Fisher's exact test on multiple columns

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I am trying to run multiple Fisher's exact tests for each column of data and then fit resulting p-values into a matrix.

I have tried the code below, which is a Fisher's test for a single column, and I got a p-value. However, I am having difficulties in making it into a loop.

```
my_matrix <- matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
all.cells <- rownames(my_data)
my_cells <- rownames(my_cluster)
active <- rownames(my_data[which(my_data[,1]>0),])
a=length(intersect(my_cells, active))
b=length(setdiff(my_cells, active))
c=length(setdiff(active, my_cells))
d=length(all.cells)-a-b-c
my_matrix[1,1]=a
my_matrix[1,2]=b
my_matrix[2,1]=c
my_matrix[2,2]=d
test.p <- fisher.test(my_matrix, alternative = 'greater')$p.value
```

My attempt to make a loop:

```
    fisher_table = matrix(ncol = length(colnames(ca.auc)), nrow = 1)
    for (a in 1:length(colnames(ca.auc))) 
{ my_matrix <- matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
    all.cells <- rownames(my_data)
    my_cells <- rownames(my_cluster)
    active <- rownames(my_data[which(my_data[,a]>0),])
    a=length(intersect(my_cells, active))
    b=length(setdiff(my_cells, active))
    c=length(setdiff(active, my_cells))
    d=length(all.cells)-a-b-c
    my_matrix[1,1]=a
    my_matrix[1,2]=b
    my_matrix[2,1]=c
    my_matrix[2,2]=d
      fisher_table[1,a]=fisher.test(my_matrix, alternative = "greater")$p.value
    }
```

My data matrix consists of 3700 rows and 442 columns. So, I wish to run Fisher's exact test per column, run it for 442 times.

I would like my resulting table to look like 2x442, So I have colnames same as my data matrix (442 gene names) and p-value per gene.

[image]

Comment: you're overwriting your iterator variable `a` within the for-loop...might be causing some issues?

Comment: @WalkerHarrison oh my god... yes I fixed a into x and it worked... such a stupid mistake. Thank you so much:')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible solution that (I think) solves your problem. First we generate some example data to work on.

```
my_data <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(5000), nrow=50)) # 50 rows, 100 columns
my_cluster <- rep(0:1, 25) # 25 in each cluster, alternating
```

Since the information in each columns needs to be converted to a 2x2 table we can iterate over the columns in `my_data` using `sapply()`. For each column we create the table with cluster indices as rows and whether the value was positive as columns. Then we pass everything to `fisher.test()`, extract the p-value and done!

```
result <- sapply(my_data, function(x) {  
              fisher.test(table(my_cluster, factor(x>0, levels=c(TRUE, FALSE))))$p
          })
names(result) <- colnames(my_data) # Copy the names
```

In the code above I'm using `factor()` with prespecified levels to ensure that the procedure runs if - by chance - there's no variation in the values for a column and they are all positive or negative.

This gives the following since I have boring column names

```
> head(result)
       V1        V2        V3        V4        V5        V6 
1.0000000 1.0000000 0.5709160 0.7688127
```